# How to populate treenode from SQL using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I inherited a project that is populating TreeNode from SQL. I want to add three columns but syntax checker doesn't like what I'm adding but appears consistent with examples in blogs.

```
TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString()); // current working code

TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["FieldType"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["PointsToFileNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["FieldLength"].ToString()); //possible replacement code that works but I would have to parse it later

TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString(), rdr["FieldType"].ToString(), rdr["PointsToFileNumber"].ToString(), rdr["FieldLength"].ToString()); //bad syntax beginning at first comma
```

Method:

```
private void getFileManFields(TreeNode node)
{
    node.Nodes.Clear();
    String fileNumber = node.Tag.ToString();
    String sta3n = cbRegionSites.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(1, 3);
    SqlConnection cdw = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CDW"].ConnectionString);
    cdw.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT VistaFieldNumber,VistaFieldName,MultipleFileNumber FROM CDWWork.Dim.VistaField WHERE Sta3n=" + sta3n + " AND VistaFileNumber='" + fileNumber + "' ORDER BY CAST(VistaFieldNumber As NUMERIC(30,10))", cdw);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT VistaFieldNumber,VistaFieldName,MultipleFileNumber,FieldType,PointsToFileNumber,FieldLength FROM CDWWork.Dim.VistaField WHERE Sta3n=" + sta3n + " AND VistaFileNumber='" + fileNumber + "' ORDER BY CAST(VistaFieldNumber As NUMERIC(30,10))", cdw);
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        //TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString());
        //TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["FieldType"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["PointsToFileNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["FieldLength"].ToString());
        TreeNode field = new TreeNode(rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString() + " - " + rdr["VistaFieldName"].ToString(), rdr["FieldType"].ToString(), rdr["PointsToFileNumber"].ToString(), rdr["FieldLength"].ToString());
        field.Tag = rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString();
        if (rdr["MultipleFileNumber"].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            field.Tag = rdr["MultipleFileNumber"].ToString();
            field.Nodes.Add("RemoveNode");
        }
        node.Nodes.Add(field);
    }
    rdr.Close();
    rdr.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
    cdw.Close();
    cdw.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and contained queries.

Comment: Of course it will not allow you to pass bunch of strings when method expects only one string. So concatenate strings for node text and use [node.tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property to store data(for example list of strings) that you'll need later.

Comment: How about using that magic [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your all your `IDisposable` instances?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have explained that this is my first exposure to C#.  Would you expand a little on use of node.tag?  Is the line field.Tag = rdr["VistaFieldNumber"].ToString(); an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: Would you give an example of using for the disposables.  I might as well put good advice to use as I learn.  Thanks

Comment: This `rdr["MultipleFileNumber"].ToString().Length > 0` is not good. Unless you store `empty string` and not `NULL` in DB